b2c login prompt option not working as expected
We've encountered some unexpected behavior with the prompt=login option in our B2C custom policies and could use some guidance.
In our environment, we utilize prompt=login for scenarios where users need to either "Sign in as a different user" or encounter a "Hi John Doe! Not you? Click here" scenarios.
Previously, this functionality worked as expected, but we're now experiencing some peculiar behavior.
Our B2C setup is linked to two upstream Identity Providers: Azure AD using SAML and Auth0 using OAuth/OIDC.
With Azure AD SAML, when utilizing prompt=login, every alternate attempt prompts the user for credentials.
For instance, after the initial sign-in, the second attempt with prompt=login signs in without prompting for a password.
However, the third attempt would prompt the user for a password, and the fourth attempt would log in directly. This pattern is consistently observed.
On the other hand, with Auth0, prompt=login seems to have no effect, and it doesn't prompt for a password at all.
SM-SocialLogin is used for session management and is configured with ClaimsProviderSelection under the same user journey.
prompt=none works as expected... skips the IdP selection step and uses existing session for signin.
In an attempt to troubleshoot, we started with a fresh copy of the "SocialAndLocalAccounts" from the starter pack and tested it with Auth0, still encountering the issue. Test was using jwt.ms
Any insights into what might be causing the issue with AzureAD and Auth0 to make prompt=login prompt for password?
--- Steps to reproduce ---
Sign in with a federated account (Entra ID) using a test application - jwt.ms
https://xxxx.b2clogin.com/xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1A_SIGNUP_SIGNIN&client_id=xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxx&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fjwt.ms&scope=openid&response_type=id_token&prompt=login
Within the same browser window, I paste the above link, opting for federated login, which then prompts for credentials by invalidating the session from previous step... this is expected and the correct experience.
I attempt the link once more, and it uses the existing session. This is my issue.
Revisiting the link will again prompt for password.
Repeat the step, and this time it would login using existing session.
When passing "prompt=login", the expected behavior is to consistently challenge the user to enter credentials. However, presently, in my environment, it operates reliably only 50% of the time.
b2c reference
Thanks.

Sorry, I'm not clear on what the question is? Are you asking why Auth0 itself doesn't respect promt=login, or are you saying that when B2C receives a prompt=login it only federates to Entra ID (Azure AD), never to Auth0?

Sorry, for not making the question clear enough.
Would like Entra ID (which is our primary IdP) and Auth0 to prompt for password.
Currently, both are not respecting prompt=login properly.
Entra ID works 50% of the time when prompt=login is passed to the url parameter.
Auth0 doesn't respect that option at all.

Updated my original question with the steps I use to reproduce the issue.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
